# Cannot hide a script inside a div or a span in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, scripting

I have a span/div tag which I try to hide a script inside

```
var wr2 = '<span id="span_id" style="display:none;position:relative"><SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="http://www.some_server.com?a=3&d=5"></SCRIPT></span>';
```

Then in my script I use (to write the code top the page):

```
document.write(wr2);
```

No matter what I do it always shows the script even if it is wrapped by a hidden div.
I would like to control that on another function but by default to have it hidden.

1. I cannot use jQuery.
2. Chrome and Firefox are working ok with this code

Comment: Scripts aren't "visible". They execute and do something. If you want to hide what they do to the page then you need to figure out what that is.

Comment: Why are you trying to conditionally hide your script? You need to rethink!!

Comment: I cannot move the script and actually I don't know where it is placed

Comment: my customer would like to conditionally hide/show the script based on params he gets from my server. the script can be shown in the page source but I should be able to block its display of images for example

Answer (score 2):

If you put your script elements in the  section of the html page, they will not display on the page, but will be visible if the user views page source.  Also, the  tag does not display, by default.  There is no need to put it in a hidden tag.

Here is a simple [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dMHzF/) to demonstrate this.

Comment: I don't need to hide it while viewing page source, just not show the image/flesh behind it until a certain point

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, hiding the script seems like a smell.

However, if you're talking about `script` tags appearing as HTML when you do `document.write`, use this:

```
document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="http://www.some_server.com?a=3&d=5" type="text/javascript">' + '</scr' + 'ipt>');
```

You won't need the `span` to hide it anymore.

Comment: I don't need to hide it while viewing page source, just not show the image/flesh behind it until a certain point

Comment: using document.write with the script will initially show the script, a thing which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Have you tried it? I've been using it with no such issues. Also, what do you mean by the image /flesh? I've never seen any script tag render any stub on the page.

Comment: I did tried it. wait for the whole page to load then use document.write see what you get - the page is entirely removed while you see only the last document.write